# AWS SDK CPP and EBS fecthing

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-cpp

Based on my research, I found out that AWS SDK CPP allows [upload/download  files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html) to bucket.

I need to have same upload/download access on an `AWS EBS`
 volume of types `st1`, but I could not find any example or tutorials about it. Is there some way to do that ? I search in the very large documentation without success.

Answer (score 1):

EBS volumes can only be accessed via EC2 instances. Unlike S3, for example, it's not a standalone service offering by AWS.

Comment: This is what I figure out. There is no API function to access it. But is there a way to access it via HTTP request ? Or ssh ?

Comment: You can only access the volumes through the ec2 instances attached to them